# Adding up subqueries with main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how can I add up the result of my subqueries within a table. For example, I want to add up the following two queries in one statement.

```
SELECT SUM(A) - (SELECT SUM(B) FROM MyTable WHERE C<A))
FROM MyTable WHERE B>C;

SELECT SUM(B) - (SELECT SUM(C) FROM MyTable WHERE D<F))
FROM MyTable WHERE B=C;
```

Comment: Could you provide real column names or some kind of fake schema that helps us to make sense of why you're doing this? Sometimes it's easier to come up with answers when there is an analogical model to relate to. Why does it make sense to do these weird column comparisons and summing/subtracting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can literally just add them together:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(A) - (SELECT SUM(B) FROM MyTable WHERE C<A))
                         FROM MyTable WHERE B>C)  
        +
        (SELECT SUM(B) - (SELECT SUM(C) FROM MyTable WHERE D<F))
                          FROM MyTable WHERE B=C)
```

Same as:

```
SELECT 5 + 3
```

You could also probably use some CASE statements to do this without the subqueries, or to make it cleaner at the least, something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN B > C THEN A ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN C < A THEN B ELSE 0 END)
       +
       SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN B ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN D < F THEN C ELSE 0 END)
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: fantastic! Simple and helpful

Comment: @Goat_CO . . . You fixed the query since my comment.  My point directed at the OP about accepting an answer that wasn't correct than on your response.  If the previous version was correct, s/he should have explained why.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the only edits were for wording and adding the CASE Statement portion.  No problem either way.

Comment: @Goat_CO The result is null, how can I show that it's 0 (zero) ? Thanks!

Comment: coalesce is the answer, I guess but what if I add select 1 + null, how can I get an actual number?

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(field,0) + ISNULL(field2,0).  ISNULL returns whatever you put after the comma if the field is NULL.  COALESCE is similar, returns first non-NULL value from the set of values you give it. If NULL's are giving you fits then you can wrap each one in an ISNULL/COALESCE statement.